# Inject a node inside XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xmlnode

I have a quick question:

using C#, how can I inject a node inside XmlNode please. I don't want to involve XmlDocument in my specific method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to pass a `XmlDocument` instance in your method parameter list, then you can get the `XmlDocument` from the `XmlNode` instance by the `OwnerDocument` property.

Like in this example:

```
public void MyMethod(XmlNode node)
{
      var newElement = node.OwnerDocument.CreateElement("element");
      node.AppendChild(newElement);
}
```

Hope this helps.